# Plink SSH access through VBA Excel and terminating the cmd prompt

Tags: excel, plink, vba

I have a macro written to go through a list of IP addresses and run SSH through the plink.exe. The IP's are for network security devices.

The output, if SSH is accessible, will be "login as:" meaning that I can SSH to the device. The output from the cmd is read to a cell in excel and it is shown in a table, as that the device is accessible.

The PROBLEM is after executing the code for top IP, plink.exe window does not closes and I have to manually close the window to loop the code again to go to the next IP. If somehow, I can close the window in the program automatically so it can run through all the IP's (there are around 100 IP's).

The important part is I don't want to send any log-in info to the cmd after "login as:". I want to terminate the program and close the cmd window just after taking the output. Your help will be appreciated.

```
Sub SSH()
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
i = 3
j = 200
While (ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3) <> "")

'Retrieve IP address from the cell

strCompAddress = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3)

Dim strShellCommand As String
Dim filename As String
Dim Run As String
Dim pointer As String

'Plink file location from a cell in different sheet
filename = Sheet1.Cells(8, 2).Value
pointer = "-ssh"

Run = filename & " " & pointer & " " & strCompAddress
Set osh = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set oEx = osh.Exec(Run)

'The output is inserted to a cell specified
strBuf = oEx.StdOut.ReadAll
ActiveSheet.Cells(j, 21) = strBuf

i = i + 1
j = j + 1
Wend
Exit Sub
ErrHandler: MsgBox "Please check the filename/address."
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out the problem. I had to make the application wait for a certain time before I could terminate it and hence was able to get the output as needed. Thanks for helping out.

```
Set oEx = osh.Exec(Run)
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:5"))
oEx.Terminate
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`Wscript.Shell.Exec`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateytk4a(v=vs.84).aspx) method returns a [`WshScriptExec`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2f38xsxe(v=vs.84).aspx) object which has a [`Terminate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk84ffsf(v=vs.84).aspx) method.  That `Terminate` method is what you are want.

You can use it like this

```
Public Sub test()

    Dim WshShell, oExec
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    Set oExec = WshShell.Exec("calc")
    oExec.Terminate

    MsgBox oExec.Status

End Sub
```

**EDIT**

Ideally you would implement this like so

```
strBuf = oEx.StdOut.ReadAll
ActiveSheet.Cells(j, 21) = strBuf
oEx.Terminate
```

However. I suspect `ReadAll` will keep reading as long as the program is running.  You want to just read one line then quit so just do that.

```
strBuf = oEx.StdOut.ReadLine
ActiveSheet.Cells(j, 21) = strBuf
oEx.Terminate ' now kill plink
```

Comment: This works before I take the output but after it doesn't work after.

Comment: Does your original code ever reach the line `ActiveSheet.Cells(j, 21) = strBuf`?  Its possible that `oEx.StdOut.ReadAll` doesn't stop reading until the application closes.

Comment: The original code prints a "login as:" if the IP is reachable through SSH and is blank if not reachable.

Comment: Oh, Ok, I will try this out and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: The plink.exe still does not closes after terminating as per your suggestion.

Comment: if `oEx.Terminate` doesn't kill plink then idk what to do.